# Having an issue with using multiple if exist and if not exist for one big task BATCH

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

So I am working on a batch file that will clean out these specific files when you open this file, but I want to make for a lot of people to release it publicly, but I'm having issues using 4 IF NOT EXIST and 4 IF EXIST lines to execute these.

*I tried looking for multiple sources or for people who have tried this, but I can't seem to find anything close to running this big of a task.*

**Here is my current code:**

````
title Zyorby Cleaner V2 \ ENB Remover
cls
if exist C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries (
    if exist D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries (
        if exist C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries (
            if exist D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries (
rmdir /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\d3d11.dll"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\d3dcompiler_46e.dll"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbadaptation.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbbloom.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbeffect.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbeffectpostpass.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblens.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblightsprite.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblocal.ini""
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries.ini"
rmdir /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\d3d11.dll"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\d3dcompiler_46e.dll"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbadaptation.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbbloom.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbeffect.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbeffectpostpass.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblens.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblightsprite.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblocal.ini"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries.ini"
rmdir /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\d3d11.dll"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\d3dcompiler_46e.dll"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbadaptation.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbbloom.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbeffect.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbeffectpostpass.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblens.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblightsprite.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblocal.ini"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries.ini"
rmdir /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\d3d11.dll"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\d3dcompiler_46e.dll"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbadaptation.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbbloom.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbeffect.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbeffectpostpass.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblens.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblightsprite.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblocal.ini"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries.ini"
echo %DATE% %TIME% - ENB has been removed >> %userprofile%\Downloads\logs.txt
cls
echo.
echo              ----------------------------------
echo              -   your ENB has been cleaned    -
echo              - to go back to the home screen: -
echo              ----------------------------------
echo.
)
)
)
)
if not exist C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries (
    if not exist D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries (
        if not exist C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries (
            if not exist D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries (
echo %DATE% %TIME% - could not find enbseries folder >> %userprofile%\Downloads\logs.txt
cls
echo.
echo           --------------------------------------
echo           -   your ENB could not be found :(   -
echo           --------------------------------------
echo.
)
)
)
)
)
pause
goto main```
````

Answer (score 0):

*I ended up fixing this pretty quickly I made a simple checklist using a lot of else's but it worked I'm not sure if there is a more efficient way but this works for me at the moment.*

---

**heres is the fixed code:**

```
:x
title Zyorby Cleaner V2 \ ENB Remover
cls

if exist "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries" (
    goto enbyes
) else (
    if exist "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries" (
        goto enbyes
    ) else (
        if exist "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries" (
            goto enbyes
            ) else (
                if exist "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries" (
                    goto enbyes
                ) else (
                    goto enbno
                )
            )
    )
)


:enbyes
rmdir /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\d3d11.dll"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\d3dcompiler_46e.dll"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbadaptation.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbbloom.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbeffect.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbeffectpostpass.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblens.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblightsprite.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblocal.ini""
del /s /q "C:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries.ini"
rmdir /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\d3d11.dll"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\d3dcompiler_46e.dll"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbadaptation.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbbloom.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbeffect.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbeffectpostpass.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblens.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblightsprite.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enblocal.ini"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files\Epic Games\GTAV\enbseries.ini"
rmdir /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\d3d11.dll"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\d3dcompiler_46e.dll"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbadaptation.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbbloom.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbeffect.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbeffectpostpass.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblens.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblightsprite.fx"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblocal.ini"
del /s /q "C:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries.ini"
rmdir /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\d3d11.dll"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\d3dcompiler_46e.dll"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbadaptation.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbbloom.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbeffect.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbeffectpostpass.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblens.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblightsprite.fx"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enblocal.ini"
del /s /q "D:\Program Files (x86)\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries.ini"
echo %DATE% %TIME% - ENB has been removed >> %userprofile%\Downloads\logs.txt
cls
echo.
echo              ----------------------------------
echo              -   your ENB has been cleaned    -
echo              - to go back to the home screen: -
echo              ----------------------------------
echo.
pause
goto main

:enbno
echo %DATE% %TIME% - could not find enbseries folder >> %userprofile%\Downloads\logs.txt
cls
echo.
echo           --------------------------------------
echo           -    your ENB could not be found     -
echo           --------------------------------------
echo.
pause
goto main
```

**Explanation:**

Basically it runs through the users files and checks if the folder is there if it is it will get sent to the :enbyes section which is just the part that deletes the folder and files, but if it can't find the folder it sends it down the chain with else and it continues to do this until it hit the end where it runs out of options. Once the code reaches there it sends it to the :enbno section which is just saying that it could not find the thing it wanted to find.

Comment: Why do you use multiple __IF - ELSE__ statements? You can use simply `if exist "%ProgramFiles%\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries" set "GamePath=%ProgramFiles%\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries" & goto DeleteGameFiles` and on next line `if exist "%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries" set "GamePath=%ProgramFiles(x86)%\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries" & goto DeleteGameFiles` and ...

Comment: ... on next line `if exist "%ProgramW6432%\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries" set "GamePath=%ProgramW6432%\Steam\steamapps\common\Grand Theft Auto V\enbseries" & goto DeleteGameFiles` and next line being an error message as the game path is not found and `goto :EOF` to exit the processing of this batch file in this error condition. Then there is the line `:DeleteGameFiles` and below the other command lines using `%GamePath%`. However, the manual deletion of files and folders is always the wrong approach. Run __uninstaller__ of the game instead of deleting its files/folders.